# Remove a column after selection with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want my result set to include only one column, but I'm using a different column to group by and order by.
Can I somehow, after selecting and order by removing the column from the result set?

Using MSSQL2008

Comment: And also show us sample table data and expected result!

Comment: what difference does it make? it's an arbitrary case..

Comment: It makes a huge difference to know what you are asking for...

Comment: Could you give an example for when it would make a difference? I'm asking something simple, it's almost as how to select from a table, what difference does it make? if it's a table of purchases or articles ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add another `SELECT` around your query, like so:

```
SELECT
     sum_columnB
FROM
(SELECT 
    columnA
    , SUM(columB) sum_columnB
FROM Table
GROUP BY columnA
ORDER BY columnA
       , sum_columnB) resultset
```

But if you would post your query, my answer could be more specific and maybe clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to select all the columns your order or group by, you can just select the column you want.

```
SELECT A
FROM dbo.Table
GROUP BY A,B
ORDER BY A,B
```